# Failed to send WebSocket Frame doesn't let my Ionic app use Firebase on iOS10

Tags: ios, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, content-security-policy

I'm programming a mobile app w/ Ionic v1, AngularJS and Firebase to manage users in a database. The app lets users log in and, once logged in, change their information (like name, birthday, etc). On iOS 9 and on my browser when I use ionic serve, everything works fine.

However, on iOS 10, the user can log in (albeit noticeably more slowly) and then, once they attempt to change their info in the database, some kind of problem is happening and no new info is writing to the database.

Since the Firebase database is perfectly functional and the new data writes without any errors on the browser and in iOS 9, I believe it may be an issue with my Content Security Policy required in iOS 10. I have tried many combinations of CSPs; some result in a "WARN: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback", and some combinations have no error but are still not writing the new information to the database.

Does anyone have experience using Ionic v1 and AngularFire on iOS 10 that can help?

Current CSP:`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">`

Edit:
Found the error inside the Safari developer console. It is failing to connect to the websocket. WebSocket connection to 'wss://stuff.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=app' failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame.

Comment: I’m wondering how this question is different from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144628/content-security-policy-on-ionic-v1-app-using-firebase question you posted, where the answer was that the problem you’re seeing is clearly not CSP-related…

Comment: I am asking for what the problem may be. I gave specific errors and details as to try to figure out the source of the error if it is not CSP related as you claim. Plus, it works in iOS 9 but not iOS 10 and the Firebase callback error is fixed with CSP editing, evidence that this may be a CSP problem.

Comment: Found an error in the Safari developer console. WebSocket connection to 'wss://stuff.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=appname' failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running into this issue for the first time, myself after upgrading to Ionic 3 and Angular 4. I never had this issue in Ionic 2, so is it related to the version of iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing kind of the same issue, with websocket being killed when I send too much data to firebase (more than 50Kb at once, a base64encoded image for example), from IOS10 only as well.

What you might be missing in your CSP is the following line :

```
connect-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.firebaseapp.com https://*.firebaseio.com wss://*.firebaseio.com blob: data:;
```

Which will allow you to send and receive data to/from firebase.